# work laptop (but not home desktop) unable to access work websites

Tags: router, wireless-networking

My wife often brings her work laptop home.  I have configured that laptop to wirelessly connect to our router.  Normally, she is able to access every website that she desires.

**However, that are certain websites at her work that when she tries to access them, the pages never load!**

After a while, her browser displays an error message about not being able to reach the site.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

This happens with every major browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge).  *So, it is probably not a browser issue.*

This problem only happens when she is using our home router: on every public WiFi we have tried (e.g. Starbucks), her laptop can access all her work websites.  *So, those work websites are not blocking public access.*

This problem does not occur with our home personal desktop: she can access all her work websites from it.  *So, it is not that our router is obviously the culprit.*

Our desktop is connected to the router by an ethernet cable, not wirelessly.  I tried plugging that ethernet cable into her work laptop, and after a bit, Windows 10 told me "No internet access".  Hmm, I have never seen cabled ethernet fail...  Not sure if this fact is related, but I thought I would mention it; it might be something that her IT at work configured?

**Summary: there appears to be some strange conflict between my router and some of her work websites, but only when the client is wirelessly connected to the router.**

I have poured thru my router's web admin interface, and I see nothing obvious.  (Tho I am not remotely a network guru, so I could easily have overlooked something.)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Work laptop:

```
Dell Latitude E7470
running latest Windows 10
```

Router:

```
Netgear WNDR3700 v2
flashed to use DD-WRT v3.0-r27506 (07/09/15) std
```

Final fact: that router used to be configured to use my VPN.  I stripped out all that config today, since I now rely on running my VPN's client software on each device that I want to use the VPN (e.g. my home desktop, but not her work laptop).  Removing that VPN config did not solve this laptop connectivity problem.

Comment: @Sven: sorry if I posted this in the wrong forum.  Please migrate it to Super User if you think that forum is the best fit.  I went by the description on https://stackexchange.com/sites#, which for Server Fault merely says "Q&A for system and network administrators".  In contrast, the description for your suggested forum, Super User, says "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users".  Those descriptions need to be changed. to what you say.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following things:

- check any DNS or proxy configuration looking for something wrong (or different from the desktop);
- check the router for any firewall or transparent proxy setting;
- check if DNS answers are OK (maybe comparing them with the desktop ones);
- if the desktop can ping the websites, try to ping them from the laptop;
- try to use (if available) other services from work like ftp or ssh.

Comment: Update: I would like to accept Enrico's answer, but I do not see any link to do that.  In particular, his suggestion to look into the DNS settings turned out to be the correct suggestion.

Comment: The reason why the laptop had issues when wirelessly connected to my router was because her Windows wireless adapter was configured to use the router for DNS, and that router used a DNS service from my VPN.  For some reason, that VPN DNS service could not find a few of her work websites. So I changed that adapter to use Cloudflare's awesome new DNS (1.1.1.1).  Now, she can see all of her work websites when wirelessly connected to my router.

Comment: The reason why the laptop had issues when wirelessly connected to my router was because her Windows wireless adapter was configured to use the router for DNS, and that router used a DNS service from my VPN.  For some reason, that VPN DNS service could not find a few of her work websites. So I changed that adapter to use Cloudflare's awesome new DNS (1.1.1.1).  Now, she can see all of her work websites when wirelessly connected to my router.